# How to get a PDF/print version of kubernetes' docs?

Tags: pdf, documentation, kubernetes

How to I generate a PDF version of the Kubernetes docs at http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/?  Or, how do I get a printout of its docs at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently have a single PDF that covers all of this.  We're looking at how we can offer that, but we don't have an answer just yet.

Comment: Why don't you put it on https://readthedocs.org/ so that while editing from github changes will reflect here. IMO.

Comment: Two years later, still looking for this @tim-hockin!

Comment: I have shell scripts which generate PDFs for offlline reading website documentation. However, generating a PDF for kubernetes demonstrated to be challenging. I guess the easiest way to do that is installing squid locally onto your laptop.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a project that tries to do that: [kubernetes pdf doc](https://github.com/dohsimpson/kubernetes-doc-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Docs layout is not user friendly. Would have been nice if there was an option to hide left sidebar. Alternatively, you can zoom in to increase page size or use browser developer tools to remove unwanted HTML dev elements from page ;)